# Do i have to pay a fee to set up a git server for private or commercial use?

Tags: git, licensing

Do i have to pay a fee to set up a git server for private or commercial use?

Thanks in advance for my stupid question.

Comment: Plus, note that BitBucket offer unlimited number of *private* repos now! https://bitbucket.org/plans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, git is free software - mostly GPL, with little bits of LGPL and other licenses mixed in.  That is sufficient to run a server.

However, that only covers the core of git - if you want to use one of the web front ends you might have other licenses to contend with.  The commonest front ends for hosting yourself, though, including gitweb and gitosis, are freely licensed.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my mind!!

Answer (score 1):

No. Git is licensed under the GPL, so it is free for use for any purpose.